# firebase stops executing js file

Tags: firebase

Ok, so in an effort to learn how firebase works, I created a short little file to do an update to my data collection.  Everything was working when I went to sleep on Monday night (05/30/2016).  I didn't change anything to the app.js file I created, and I didn't touch it on Tuesday because I was traveling.  So, then today, Wednesday (06/01/2016), I ran my app.js file, and it hangs at line 25.  It posts the newPostKey to the console, but then doesn't do anything else.  It does not continue executing the rest of the app.js file.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?  Or has firebase changed something? (NOTE re: authentication - my rules are setup so anyone can write, but only authenticated users can read.)
Here is a copy of the code (less my security keys):

```
    // Initialize Firebase

var config = {
    apiKey: "",
    authDomain: "",
    databaseURL: "",
    storageBucket: "",
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
var database = firebase.database();
var auth = firebase.auth();


$(document).ready(function () {
/* Test of the Update functionality */
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user = result.user;
        console.log(user); //this works at this point
        var donationsCollection = database.ref('donations');
        var newPostKey = donationsCollection.child('donations').push().key;
        console.log(newPostKey); //it does post a key to the console
        var postData = {
            amount: '125.00',
            givingType: 'General Donation',
            memo: 'It is just optional',
            fullName: user.displayName,
            emailAddress: user.email,
            mobileNbr: '123-555-1212',
            uid: uid
        };
        // nothing comes out at the command line anymore
        console.log("You stored data in the var postData " + postData); 
        var myDonation = database.ref('/donations/' + newPostKey);
        myDonation.update(postData);  //nothing happens here anymore
})
```

Comment: Just trying to nail this down, it seems when I add breakpoints and try and step through this script, the firebase.js file is catching an error on line 2904.  The code block is 
 var e = rd(null , null , null );
        e.child = new H(function(a, g) {
            e.wa = b ? function(c) {
                try {
                    var e = b.call(d, c);
                    a(e)
                } catch (S) {
                    g(S)
                }
            }

Answer (score 1):

Well, I finally was able to figure (with the help of my friend).  Somehow, the variable declaration for uid (var uid = result.user.uid;) was deleted.  As soon as I added it back in I was able to post to the database again.